# Вывод столбцов с независимыми условиями в SQL

Tags: mysql

Я уверен, что мой вопрос довольно просто решается, но всё же я никак не могу понять, как мне сделать следующее:

Есть таблица country. В ней множество столбцов, но в данном случае меня интересуют только два из них: SurfaceArea (площадь страны), Name (название страны).

Требование к запросу звучит так:
Вывести количество стран с площадью больше 5000. Очевидно, что запрос выглядит так:

**SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM country WHERE SurfaceArea > 5000**

И, наконец, мой вопрос заключается в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы в одном столбце были ВСЕ страны, площадь которых больше 5000, а в другом столбце была одна запись с этих количеством стран.

1 скриншот - То, чего нужно добиться (нарисовал в paint).

[image: То, чего нужно добиться (нарисовал в paint)]

Все, что я придумал, это вот этот запрос:

**SELECT NAME, COUNT(Name) FROM country WHERE SurfaceArea > 5000;**

Но он выводит только первую страну и, соответственно, число всех стран с площадью более 5000.

2 скриншот - То, что у меня получилось

[image: То, что у меня получилось]

Comment: это скажем прямо весьма странная выборка. для каких целей она вам такая нужна вообще?

Comment: Я понимаю, что это довольно странный вопрос, но у меня просто задание в университете такое.

Comment: задание то по какой дисциплине? а то вдруг, вывести надо на пхп, а вы хотите решить задачу средствами sql

Comment: Есть два варианта. 1) В КАЖДОЙ записи получить количество - но показать его один раз. 2) Получить количество отдельно, на экране показать две несвязанные таблицы, выглядящие, как одна таблица.

Comment: *Или я что-то не так понял?* Угу... не мешай в кучу получение данных с сервера (2 разных запроса) и отображение результата на экране (оба набора выводим в одну таблицу).

Comment: @Akina сказано же, что дисциплина - БД, нет там никаких выводов никуда.

Comment: В общем, в следующем запросе я путем подзапроса создал копию таблицы country, которая называется TempCountry и попытался вывести два несвязанных столбца из разных таблиц, но на выходе получил что-то непонятное. Ошибки не вижу. Запрос: SELECT NAME.country, COUNT(NAME).TempCountry FROM country, (SELECT * INTO TempCountry FROM country) WHERE SurfaceArea > 5000;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вообще говоря, решений можно придумать несколько, и возможно оно должно зависеть от конкретной темы, которую вы изучаете.
Можно, например, пронумеровать строки, и только для первой подзапросом вывести общее число стран.

а можно, например, сначала выбрать первую страну и общее число, а потом с помощью `union` прицепить к нему оставшиеся страны.

```
(
  SELECT name, count(name) 
  FROM  x
  GROUP BY  name
  ORDER BY name
  LIMIT 1
)    
UNION
(
  SELECT name, null
  FROM  x
  ORDER BY name 
  LIMIT 1, 99999
)
```